# PHP - HTML Form com mais de dois botões e cada um executar uma ação diferente

Tags: php, html

Preciso criar um formulário que cria, exclui, e edita um registro em meu banco de dados. Minha dúvida é: Como fazer para ele executar uma ação ao clicar o botão?

Se eu clico em qualquer botão ele só executa a ação de salvar.

Os botões precisam estar com os icones, e não apenas escrito 'Salvar'.

Segue os códigos:

> cadastroCliente.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cadastrar cliente - World Bikes</title>
    <link href="css/ordemstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/fundo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body id="fundo">
    <img src="css/img/logo.png" alt="World Bikes" width="20%">

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>
            <li><a href="cadastro.html">Cadastro</a></li>
            <li><a href="ordemServico.html">Ordem de Serviço</a></li>
           <li><a class="active" href="cadastroCliente.html">Cadastrar Cliente</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <hr style="background-color: #33c208">

    <h1 id="titulo">Cadastro de Cliente</h1>

    <div id=form2>
        <form method="post" action="salvarCliente.php">
            <fieldset id=borda>
                <label for="cpf">CPF: </label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" class="campo1" />
                <div class="button">
                    <input src="icons/buscar.png" type="image">
                </div>
                <br />
                <label for="name">Nome do cliente:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
                <br />
                <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" />
                <br />

                <label for="modelo">Modelo da bicicleta:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="modelo" id="modelo" />
                <br />
                <label for="aro">Aro da bicicleta: </label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="aro" id="aro" />
                <br />
                <label for="cor">Cor da bicicleta:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="cor" id="cor" />
                <br />
                <div class="button">
                    <input type="image" name="salvar" src="icons/Salvar2.png">
                   <input type="image" name="excluir src="icons/excluir4.png">
                    <input type="image" name="salvar" src="icons/Editar4.png">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
          </div>

         </body>


        </html>
```

> salvarCliente.php

```
  <?php

  //conectar no banco de dados - incluir o arquivo do banco

  if($_POST){


    include "conecta.php";

//pega as variaveis vindas do formulario
$nome = ($_POST["nome"]);
$cpf = trim($_POST["cpf"]);
$telefone = trim($_POST["telefone"]);
$modelo = trim($_POST["modelo"]);
$aro = trim($_POST["aro"]);
$cor = trim($_POST["cor"]);


// para validar os campos em branco.
if (empty($nome)) {
    //se o login estiver em branco exibe esta mensagem: "preencha o login"
    echo "<script>alert('Preencha o nome');history.back();</script>";
}
if (empty($cpf)) {

    echo "<script>alert('Preencha o campo CPF');history.back();</script>";
}
if (empty($telefone)) {

    echo "<script>alert('Preencha o campo telefone');history.back( </script>";
}
if (empty($modelo)) {

    echo "<script>alert('Preencha o campo modelo');history.back();</script>";
}
if (empty($aro)) {

    echo "<script>alert('Preencha o campo aro');history.back();</script>";
}
if (empty($cor)) {

    echo "<script>alert('Preencha o campo cor');history.back();</script>";
}
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (nome, cpf, telefone, modelo, aro, cor)
     VALUES ('$nome', '$cpf', '$telefone', '$modelo','$aro','$cor')"; 
     mysqli_select_db($_SG['link'],"oficina") or die ("Banco de Dados Inexistente!"); 
    //inserindo dados no banco
    mysqli_query($_SG['link'], $sql)
     or die ("<script>alert('Erro na gravação');history.back();</script>"); 

     echo "<script>alert('Cliente  cadastrado');window.location.href='ordemServico.html';</script>";

    }

    }

  ?>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png veja porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo com as declarações, insert, delete e upadate, inclusive um exemplo funcional que estará ativo por um tempo determinado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, cada cliente deve ter uma identificação única no banco de dados.
Uma sugestão é uma coluna índice `UNIQUE` para quando fizer uma edição ou exclusão não haver problemas.

**Para essa resposta vou considerar que a coluna cpf seja do tipo `UNIQUE`.**

> Os botões devem ter `names` diferentes e não devem ser `type image` porque não podem transportar um valor para o servidor.

Você pode usar suas imagens, desde que elas façam parte de um [**`<button>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) ou utilize jquery.

```
  <button type="submit" name="salvar"><img src="cons/Salvar2.png"></button>
  <button type="submit" name="excluir"><img src="icons/excluir4.png"></button>
  <button type="submit" name="editar"><img src="icons/Editar4.png"></button>
```

**No PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['excluir'])){
    //recupere o valor do cpf
    $cpf=$_POST['cpf'];
    $sql = ("DELETE FROM cliente Where cpf='$cpf'");
}else{
    //recupere os valores dos campos
    //validação dos campos
    if(isset($_POST['salvar'])){
        //faça o INSERT
    }else{
       //faça o UPDATE
    }
}
```

### Exemplo com as declarações MySQL

**PHP**

```
if($_POST["cpf"]){

        //**********conexão*********

        #Conecta banco de dados 
        $myHost = "localhost"; // use seu nome de host
        $myUserName = "USUARIO";   // nome de usuário
        $myPassword = "SENHA";   // sua senha de login
        $myDataBaseName = "Nome_DB"; // nome do banco de dados

        $con = mysqli_connect( $myHost, $myUserName, $myPassword, $myDataBaseName ); 

        // Checa conexão
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
            echo "Falha na conexão MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

   $cpf = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["cpf"]);
   // Inclui o arquivo com a função valida_cpf
   include('valida-cpf.php');

   // Verifica o CPF
   if ( !valida_cpf( $cpf ) ) {
      echo "CPF <span style='color:red'>" .$cpf. "</span> inváido.";
   }else{

      //verifica se existe cpf no banco
      $consulta = ("SELECT * FROM cliente Where cpf='$cpf'");
      $buscar=mysqli_query($con,$consulta);
      $dados=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar);   
      $result=mysqli_num_rows($buscar);

        if(isset($_POST['buscar'])){

            //se existir o cpf retorna os dados do banco

            if ($result===1) {
                //esses dados serão os values dos campos da tabela
                $nome = $dados["nome"];
                $telefone = $dados["telefone"];
                $modelo = $dados["modelo"];
                $aro = $dados["aro"];
                $cor = $dados["cor"];

            }else{
                echo "Registro não encontrado";
            }


        }elseif(isset($_POST['excluir'])){
            if ($result===1) {
                $delete1=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM cliente Where cpf='$cpf'");
                echo "DELETE executado com sucesso!";

            }else{

                echo "DELETE não executado, CPF <span style='color:red'>" .$cpf. "</span> não encontrado";
            }

        }else{

            //recupere os valores dos campos
            $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["nome"]);
            $telefone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["telefone"]);
            $modelo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["modelo"]);
            $aro = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["aro"]);
            $cor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["cor"]);

            //faça as validações dos campos aqui

            if(isset($_POST['salvar'])){
                if ($result===0) {
                    //faça o INSERT

                    $sql = 'INSERT INTO cliente (nome, cpf, telefone, modelo, aro, cor) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

                    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

                    $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $nome, $cpf, $telefone, $modelo, $aro, $cor);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    echo "INSERT executado com sucesso!";
                }else{
                    echo "Registro com cpf= <span style='color:red'>" .$cpf. "</span>  já existente";
                }


            }else{

               if ($result===1) {
               //faça o UPDATE

                   $con->query("UPDATE cliente SET nome='$nome', cpf = '$cpf', telefone = '$telefone', modelo = '$modelo', aro = '$aro', cor = '$cor' WHERE cpf='$cpf'");

                   echo "UPDATE realizado com sucesso!";

               }else{
                    echo "UPDATE não executado, CPF <span style='color:red'>" .$cpf. "</span> não encontrado";
               }

            } //post salvar

       } //post buscar

   } // valida cpf

   mysqli_close($con);

} //post cpf
```

**valida-cpf.php**

> Obs: A validação de CPF é realizada com base nos dígitos verificadores conforme o algoritmo do CPF. Um CPF declarado como válido por este verificador não significa que ele exista no Cadastro Nacional de Pessoas Físicas nem que ele seja um número ativo ou com situação cadastral regular.

```
function valida_cpf( $cpf = false ) {

    if ( ! function_exists('calc_digitos_posicoes') ) {
        function calc_digitos_posicoes( $digitos, $posicoes = 10, $soma_digitos = 0 ) {

            for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen( $digitos ); $i++  ) {
                $soma_digitos = $soma_digitos + ( $digitos[$i] * $posicoes );
                $posicoes--;
            }

            $soma_digitos = $soma_digitos % 11;

            if ( $soma_digitos < 2 ) {
                $soma_digitos = 0;
            } else {
                $soma_digitos = 11 - $soma_digitos;
            }

            $cpf = $digitos . $soma_digitos;

            return $cpf;
        }
    }

    // Verifica se o CPF foi enviado
    if ( ! $cpf ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Remove tudo que não é número do CPF
    $cpf = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/is', '', $cpf );

    // Verifica se o CPF tem 11 caracteres
    if ( strlen( $cpf ) != 11 ) {
        return false;
    }   

    // Captura os 9 primeiros dígitos do CPF
    $digitos = substr($cpf, 0, 9);

    // Faz o cálculo dos 9 primeiros dígitos do CPF para obter o primeiro dígito
    $novo_cpf = calc_digitos_posicoes( $digitos );

    // Faz o cálculo dos 10 dígitos do CPF para obter o último dígito
    $novo_cpf = calc_digitos_posicoes( $novo_cpf, 11 );

    // Verifica se o novo CPF gerado é idêntico ao CPF enviado
    if ( $novo_cpf === $cpf ) {
        // CPF válido
        return true;
    } else {
        // CPF inválido
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id=form2>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <fieldset id=borda>
            <label for="cpf">CPF: </label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" class="campo1" value="<?php echo $cpf ?>"/>
            <div class="button">
                <button type="submit" name="buscar"><img src="icons/buscar.png"></button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <label for="name">Nome do cliente:</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" value="<?php echo $nome ?>" />
            <br />
            <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" value="<?php echo $telefone ?>" />
            <br />

            <label for="modelo">Modelo da bicicleta:</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="modelo" id="modelo" value="<?php echo $modelo ?>" />
            <br />
            <label for="aro">Aro da bicicleta: </label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="aro" id="aro" value="<?php echo $aro ?>" />
            <br />
            <label for="cor">Cor da bicicleta:</label>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="cor" id="cor" value="<?php echo $cor ?>" />
            <br />
            <div class="button">
              <button type="submit" name="salvar"><img src="icons/Salvar2.png"></button>
              <button type="submit" name="excluir"><img src="icons/excluir4.png"></button>
              <button type="submit" name="editar"><img src="icons/Editar4.png"></button>
           </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, funcionou *.*

Answer (score 0):

No ponto onde tem os botçoes no seu HTML, coloque funções javascript:

```
<div class="button">
   <input type="image" 
          name="salvar" 
          src="icons/Salvar2.png"
          onclick="salvarCliente()">
   <input type="image" 
          name="excluir"
          src="icons/excluir4.png"
          onclick="excluirCliente()">
   <input type="image" 
          name="salvar"
          src="icons/Editar4.png"
          onclick="editarCliente()">
</div>
```

Depois, crie um ponto com javascript, seja no documento do projeto, ou em um outro separado, fica a seu critério.

```
<script>
   function salvarCliente() {
      // Recupere os dados dos inputs
      // Crie uma requisição via ajax
      // Dê uma resposta ao usuário em relação a transação
   }

   function editarCliente() {
      // Recupere os dados dos inputs
      // Crie uma requisição via ajax
      // Dê uma resposta ao usuário em relação a transação
   }

   function excluirCliente() {
      // Recupere o cpf dados dos inputs
      // Crie uma requisição via ajax
      // Dê uma resposta ao usuário em relação a transação
   }
</script>
```

Mas lembre-se, este é um exemplo muito genérico, apenas para que você saiba como começar a avançar.
Caso não conheça Javascript, Ajax e etc, consulte as perguntas aqui da comunidade que você irá encontrar várias "receitas" de como fazer algo parecido com o que está precisando.